# What is difference between fetching, accessing and downloading in web?

Tags: computer-networks

I need more clarity about what is the main difference between fetching, accessing and downloading in web? which is differentiating these three words in web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Accessing** a resource (a file or a device) basically refers to using it or performing any operation on it. For example, accessing a document stored on a cloud platform includes viewing as well editing the document (and any other operations that can be performed on it).

**Fetching** and **Downloading** basically mean the same: transfer a file from a remote device (for example, a server) to your own device. A slight difference between the two is that generally, downloading saves the file to your local storage while fetching doesn't necessarily do it. For example, online streaming is also a type of fetching but it doesn't save the video locally.

These are the general meanings of the above terms related to web. Meanings may be different in any specific context (like any specific application or programming language).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: 1) This answer is not specific to the web, like the question asked. It would be good to add web-specific info.
2) I think downloading is fetching to store the results. Downloading is opposed to viewing, which also fetches the document, but just displays it in the browser. To the server and the network, the operation is the same, but to the client and end user, it is not: downloading produces a file on the file system the user can open later (unless they change their mind and decide not to save the file after all).

Comment: @reinierpost, thanks for your advice. I have edited my answer and tried to make it more web-specific and added web-related context to it. I have also tried to refine the difference between downloading and fetching. Any other suggestions are welcome.